Random girl + repressive law (Conditional probability question)
This question is a variant of the "boy-girl paradox." Suppose there are two children, and you randomly run into one of the children and they are a girl (we can assume the child you don't run into is at home or something). Furthermore, suppose that there is a repressive law such that boys cannot leave the house if they have a sister. What is the conditional probability that both children are girls?
If we let A be the event where both children are girls, and B be the event where we run into a girl, how can I find $P(B)$ so that I can apply the definition of conditional probability? I believe it should be $\frac{3}{4}$ and thus $P(A \mid B) = \frac{1}{3}$ but I don't know why.

I don't know. Comparing with each girl from a family of two girls, would a girl who has a brother leave the house for twice the duration? Or comparing with one family of two girls, is it half as likely to run into some children from one particular family of one girl and one boy?

There's no temporal aspect to this problem; I wanted to use the naive definition of probability, but in this case you cannot because the outcomes are not equally likely (running into a boy when one child is a boy and the other is a girl is impossible). I believe the second sentence you said is correct but I don't have a justification as to why.

For instance, I think when choosing the sample space you'd set the outcomes as triples, the first entry being the gender of the 1st child, the second entry being the gender of the second and the third entry as which child you ran into (because that's random). I think that setting the outcomes (B, G, 1) and (G, B, 2) to probability 0 makes sense because they're impossible, and thus (G, B, 1) and (B, G, 2) have probability $\frac{1}{4}$. The other outcomes have probability $\frac{1}{8}$ because there are 8 outcomes total. However I can't actually justify why I should do this..

If you double each probability of (G, B, 1) and (B, G, 2) to $\frac 14$, which is twice of the probability of (G, G, 1), then this is what I considered as "a girl who has a brother would leave the house for twice the duration", so that at all time some child from the (G, B, *) family is out.

I don't understand. You say boys can't leave the house if they have a sister. So either it is another girl (in or out of house) or a boy (in house). So what's the issue ?

Do two boy families allow a child to leave as often as two girl families?  Do two girl families still only allow one child to leave at a time?

Premise: A two-child family consists of two girls, one of each, or two boys with given probabilities.  Call the event of encountering a child from each type $A_2, A_1,$ and $A_0$.  With the presumption† that family makeup does not bias the probability for encountering a child:
$$\mathsf P(A_2)=1/4\\\mathsf P(A_1)=1/2\\\mathsf P(A_0)=1/4$$
Premise 2: If a girl is in the family, an encountered child shall always be a girl, otherwise it shall be a boy. Calling $B$ the event of encountering a girl.
$$\mathsf P(B\mid A_2)=1\\\mathsf P(B\mid A_1)=1\\\mathsf P(B\mid A_0)=0$$
We want $\mathsf P(A_2\mid B)$, the probability for the two child family having two girls when we encounter a girl.
$$\mathsf P(A_2\mid B) = \dfrac{\mathsf P(A_2)\mathsf P(B\mid A_2)}{\mathsf P(A_2)\mathsf P(B\mid A_2)+\mathsf P(A_1)\mathsf P(B\mid A_1)+\mathsf P(A_0)\mathsf P(B\mid A_0)}$$

$\dagger$ The presumption is that the repressive law does not influence the likely hood a child leaving the house if there are boys in the family, or that same-sexed child families still only allow one child to leave at a time.  But how justified is this presumption?
